# How can I get data out of this class in an effective way?

Tags: python

I am trying to get data live from an f1 game. Currently I am able to access the classes that hold the data. but can't get the data out of them. The problem is that the class seems to have no attributes. Here is my code so far:

```
from f1_2020_telemetry.packets import unpack_udp_packet
import socket
import f1_2020_telemetry.packets

udp_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_socket.bind(("", 20777))

while True:
    udp_packet = udp_socket.recv(2048)  # Reading udp-packet
    packet = unpack_udp_packet(udp_packet)  # Packing up udp-packet

    if isinstance(packet, f1_2020_telemetry.packets.PacketLapData_V1):
        print(type(packet))
        break
```

Output: `<class 'f1_2020_telemetry.packets.PacketLapData_V1'>`

If I type it like this:

```
if isinstance(packet, f1_2020_telemetry.packets.PacketLapData_V1):
    print(packet)
    break
```

the output will be:
`PacketLapData_V1(header=PacketHeader(packetFormat=2020, gameMajorVersion=1, gameMinorVersion=19), lapData=[LapData_V1(lastLapTime=111.75323486328125, currentLapTime=1004.9793701171875), LapData_V1(lastLapTime=98.846435546875, currentLapTime=23.304824829101562), LapData_V1(lastLapTime=100.474609375, currentLapTime=84.88221740722656)])`

So I know the iformation is there, but i cant access it with for example `packet.lastLapTime`.
What surprises me is that `packet.__dict__` returns 0. I am able to read the whole thing as a string, and slice and split it, but would like to know an easier way to handle this.

Link to site with info about the packets:
https://forums.codemasters.com/topic/50942-f1-2020-udp-specification/
Link to the library I am using:
https://gitlab.com/gparent/f1-2020-telemetry/

Comment: I cannot got `packet` (freeze at udp_socket.recv(2048) ) but what's `packer.lapData[0].lastLapTime` return?

Comment: Thank you very much, it returns exactly what I am looking for. Now I can put packet.lapData[CAR_ID].lastLapTime to find it for every car.